# How do i connect my webMethods REStful service to my spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, webmethods

All i wanted to know is that if i have a flow service in SoftwareAG webMethods and i have converted it into a REStful service by making a rest resource and i have exposed it, so how do i make a call to that service via a spring boot appplication.

This is my code for the my spring application, Can someone please suggest me that how do i make a rest call to a webMethods Rest Resource flow service which is already been exposed.

A quick help is appreciated.

```
package com.scb.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.scb.entity.ReadingEntity;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;


@RestController
public class PreProcessorController {

    private List<ReadingEntity> myEntity=new ArrayList();
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping("/GetData")
    public void getData(@RequestBody ReadingSCBMLEntity entity) {
        //myEntity.add(entity);
        final String uri="http://uklvadapp881.uk.dev.net:5555/invoke/scb.wb.fm.support.flow.ResourceGet/_get?";

        RestTemplate template=new RestTemplate();
         String result=template.getForObject(uri, String.class);

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with making a REST call to the webMethods REST service? Isn't it only a plain http call as with any other REST resource? What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Actually i wanted to know that if i am making a call to webMethods REST resource for doing lets say CRUD operation and i want to call that REST resource via my Spring Application then how do i go about it?

Comment: Then I would say just use the standard RestTemplate and make the call as you would for any other REST resource. It really is the same. webMethods IntegrationServer can describe your REST resources using Swagger. So I would suggest you take this Swagger document as your basis for how to connect with your RestTemplate.